# Invoke in Windows Forms

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++, invoke

Does anyone have a link to a learning resource for using Invoke?

I'm trying to learn but all the examples I have seen I have been unable to adapt for my purposes.

Comment: It would help to be more specific about your purposes.

Comment: Sorry, I'm writing a program which communicates with a device via a serial connection. Currently, the program tries to run a section of code until an input changes, however the section is on a GUI thread and so the program can't respond to changes. I've been told I therefore need to put the section of code on another thread and use Invoke to access it. Hope this helps, thanks

Comment: please next time update your question instead of writing it in the comment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Did you try MSDN [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx)

I just wrote a little WinForm application to demonstrate Control.Invoke. 
When the form is created, Start some work on background thread. After that work is done, Update the status in a label.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //Do some work on a new thread
    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(BackgroundWork);
    backgroundThread.Start();
}        

private void BackgroundWork()
{
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < 5)
    {
        counter++;
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }

    DoWorkOnUI();
}

private void DoWorkOnUI()
{
    MethodInvoker methodInvokerDelegate = delegate() 
                { label1.Text = "Updated From UI"; };

    //This will be true if Current thread is not UI thread.
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
        this.Invoke(methodInvokerDelegate);
    else
        methodInvokerDelegate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is great, exactly what I was looking for! I have been trying to use Control.Invoke but didn't really understand what I was doing. 

One question though - I'm getting an error: 
"'delegate': identifier not found"

Thanks!

Comment: @Luke What version of .Net are you using?