# Try catch with a delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, try-catch

I am entering someone else's codebase in c# as a previously c++ coder.  All over his code I find snippets that look like this:

```
MethodInvoker invoker = new MethodInvoker
      (delegate()
      {
        ...
      }
      );
try
{
   this.Invoke(invoker);
}
catch (Exception x)
{
  ...
}
```

My question is: Is there any reason to be using a `delegate` and then the try-catch?  Can the code inside the curly braces on the third to fifth lines not just be placed inside that try catch?  Is there some nuance of c# I do not yet know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not just invoke the delegate but passes it to a method called `Invoke`.

It's more of a nuance of the UI framework/enviroment your working with. In WinForms for example, there is only one GUI thread that can change UI controls' state. If you want to change a control's state from some other thread, you need to call Invoke method and pass a delegate, just like in your example. Calling `Invoke` basically means "run this delegate on the GUI thread".

See these questions: [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)
[Invoke in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650691/invoke-in-windows-forms)

And Control.Invoke documentation: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx

Answer (score 0):

what you are  doing here is `defining  a simple anonymous method` that will  be invoked  later on `winform's Control thread`

```
MethodInvoker invoker = new MethodInvoker
      (delegate()
      {
        ...
      }
      );
```

what you are doing next is `the execution` of the anonymous method

```
try
{
   this.Invoke(invoker);
}
catch (Exception x)
{
  ...
}
```

*`Can the code inside the curly braces on the third to fifth lines not just be placed inside that try catch?`*

yes you  can just do something like this  ([MethodInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

```
try
    {
       this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
      {
       //
      }
      ));
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
      ...
    }
```