# How to modify UI elements from async c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, user-interface, async-await

I need to add in a form.listwiew some rows but i need to add them dinamyically while my async function is processing...
I have read that is not possible to do this from an async method. Anyway i have to do this ... any other method or solution?
Example:

```
private async Task start(CancellationToken token)
        {      
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
             //do something and then modify UI
             Guiadjust("",1); //function that add rows

            },token);
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is TaskCanceledException)
                CustomMessageBox.Show("Unaxpected error", ex.ToString());
        }
      }
```

Function to add rows to list graphical form element that doesn't work because called from async method, instead it should normally work!

```
private void Guiadjust(string cc, int ff)
{

    string[] row = { "Working", "", "" };
    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
    list.Items.Add(listViewItem);
}
```

Calling the function:

```
await start(cts.Token);
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: this doesn't work.... no rows are added from my async function. And i need to add rows dinamically to the UI

Comment: hint : you're looking for `Control.Invoke` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650691/invoke-in-windows-forms

Comment: You could update UI this way: `this.Invoke(() => list.Items.Add(listViewItem));`

Comment: Cannot convert with invoke from System.....ListViewItem to System.Delegate

Comment: You _can_ update the GUI  from an async method, but you _cannot_  update the GUI  from a `Task.Run()`. You simplified too much to get a good answer.